# Javascript: filter array of objects by array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I wonder if there is a more elegant way of doing this. Suppose i have an array of objects like this:

```
a = [
  {
    "id": "kpi02",
    "value": 10
  },
  {
    "id": "kpi02",
    "value": 30
  },
  {
    "id": "kpi02",
    "value": 11
  },
  {
    "id": "kpi02",
    "value": 33
  },
  {
    "id": "kpi03",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "kpi03",
    "value": 0.5
  },
  {
    "id": "kpi04",
    "value": 0.5
  }
]
```

Now i want to filter on the `id` property, to return all objects with a match in another array

```
var kpis = ["kpi03", "kpi02"];
```

I came up with this solution:

```
var b = [];
for (j in kpis) {
 for (i in a) { 
    if (a[i].id == kpis[j]) {
    b.push(a[i]);
    }
 }
}
```

Coming from R, this seems a bit complicated, is there any way to do that with the `filter` prototype? Like this but with an array of strings to compare with instead of a single string:

```
 var b = a.filter( function(item){return (item.id == "kpi03");} );
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) in filter, like this

```
var res = a.filter(function (el) {
  return kpis.indexOf(el.id) >= 0; 
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/kovora/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and the example! I knew there must be a more elegant solution :)

Answer (score 14):

Another nice alternative is using [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with  [.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
var result = a.filter(item => kpis.includes(item.id))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want them in the order of the array of string then

```
    var result = [];
kpis.map((item) => {
    const matchedObject = a.find(
        (option) => option.id === item
    );
    result.push(matchedObject);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make use of [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
var b = a.filter(function(item){return kpids.indexOf(item.id) > -1 });
```

`Array.indexOf` returns the index of the argument passed in the array on which `indexOf` is being called on. It returns `-1` if there isn't the element which we are looking for.

So, we make sure that it index is greater than -1