# Go through array of objects and return objects that have Ids from an array of Ids

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, lodash

I want to use Lodash to its full capability and i don't see why i could not perform this with Lodash.

I have an array of 38 objects that all have ID's. I also have another array of Id's. I need to map these to the array of objects and have them available in a new array of objects.

I was looking at a solution like this:

```
 var workOrder.model.Lands = [{
                ID: "123",
                LandArea: "",
                LandAreaDescription: "something",
                LandAreaNo: 0,
                Value: null,
                Text: null,
                Status: true,
                GeoJsonData: null,
                GeoJsonCenter: null,
                Blocks: Array[3]
            },...];

var landIDs = [1, 2, 3, 4];


_.each(workOrder.model.Lands, function(land){
     _.each(landIDs, function(id){
         console.log(id);
         if(land.ID === id){
              workOrder.selectedLandArea.push(land);
          }
     });
});
```

This does not work and actually returns me all the items in the Lands collections. What is the best solution to get these objects out?

*NO JQUERY*

Thanks in advance

*Update*
Added variables to make more clearity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: filter array of objects by array of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138139/javascript-filter-array-of-objects-by-array-of-strings)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I have updated this

Comment: @Keeano your example still doesn't make much sense. none of the `landIDs` are equal to the ID in the first object, they're not even the same type. Are you trying to _reorder_ the array based on the order of `landIDs`?

Comment: you want to filter your array of objects with the ids contained in your `landIDs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/265dLj3c/)

Here's the relevant code (assuming `objs` is the object array and `ids` is the id array)

```
_.filter(objs, function(obj) {
  return _.includes(ids, obj.ID);
});
```

Logically, you're filtering a set based on member keys included in another set.

Comment: Thank you @user01 this answers my question because i was looking for a 100% lodash method.