# Filtering an array against another array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 arrays like this ...

```js
var heroes = [{
    name: "Batman",
    franchise: "DC"
  },
  {
    name: "Ironman",
    franchise: "Marvel"
  },
  {
    name: "Thor",
    franchise: "Marvel"
  },
  {
    name: "Superman",
    franchise: "DC"
  }
];

var stars = ["Thor", "Superman"];

var marvelHeroes = heroes.filter(function(hero) {
  return stars.indexOf(hero.name) >= 0;
});

console.log(marvelHeroes);
```

This code is returning 'undefined'. So essentially I am trying to filter an array against values in another array.

Can someone please advise what am I doing wrong ? Thanks

My expected output is an array of objects like the following ...

```
[
{name: "Thor", franchise: "Marvel"},
{name: "Superman", franchise: "DC"}
];
```

I have seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138139), but that solution is not working for me ...

Comment: Which `hero` are you trying to select? Select with `hero[index].name`

Comment: I converted your code to a snippet and logged the object to the console. It works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be just  return **`stars.indexOf(item.name) !== -1 ;`**

**DEMO**

```js
var heroes = [
    {name: "Batman", franchise: "DC"},
    {name: "Ironman", franchise: "Marvel"},
    {name: "Thor", franchise: "Marvel"},
    {name: "Superman", franchise: "DC"}
];

var stars = ["Thor","Superman"];

var filtered = heroes.filter(function(item) {
        return stars .indexOf(item.name) !== -1 ;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: `>= 0` is `> -1`.

Comment: Because the OP's code is working correctly. Please see the snippet. This question should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: but he has mentioned it returns undefined

Comment: I understand, but for clarification, a comment would have sufficed.

Comment: Same question, I am not sure why @31piy down-voted my question as well ? People ask questions, because they are not sure about their code. This is wrong use of a down-vote.

Comment: @Slyper -- I agree that this site is meant for the questions to be asked. But, on the other hand. if the problem cannot be reproduced, your question is to be closed as off-topic here.

Comment: @31py, If you run my code as it was, it was returning "undefined". What was there to reproduce ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `includes` to determine whether an array includes a certain element

```js
var heroes = [{name:"Batman",franchise:"DC"},{name:"Ironman",franchise:"Marvel"},{name:"Thor",franchise:"Marvel"},{name:"Superman",franchise:"DC"}];
var stars = ["Thor", "Superman"];

var marvelHeroes = heroes.filter(function(hero) {
  return stars.includes(hero.name);
});

console.log(marvelHeroes);
```

For shorter code:

```js
var heroes = [{name:"Batman",franchise:"DC"},{name:"Ironman",franchise:"Marvel"},{name:"Thor",franchise:"Marvel"},{name:"Superman",franchise:"DC"}]
var stars = ["Thor", "Superman"];

var marvelHeroes = heroes.filter(o => stars.includes(o.name));

console.log( marvelHeroes );
```

Doc: [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Thanks @Eddie, From a performance point of view, which one is faster ? 'indexof' or 'includes'. My array is huge so performance is important.

Comment: I like using `includes()` because it clearer Im not sure about the performance though.

Comment: Hey @Eddie, I didn't down-voted, I think its 31piy, who down-voted my question initially, as well as all the answers. See the conversation in Sajeetharan's reply above.